# How to define a function that you can define again to do something?

Tags: python, function

So let's say I want to have a static function called `repeatForever`, that looks like this:

```
while True:
    # code that gets defined here
```

I have seen many functions, that you can "re-define" using the `def` keyword, like so (the function is defined in advance, I just "pass the code as a parameter").

```
def repeatForever():
    print("This should get printed forever!")
```

And that would be the same as;

```
while True:
    print("This should get printed forever!")
```

How can I define a function like that?

Comment: What's your question? `while True:` isn't a function. The `def` keyword is used to define a function. Those are not the same

Comment: How can i define a function like that?

Comment: `def repeatForever(): while True: #Do something`

Comment: No, i mean like I can define a function in advance, and i just have to "pass my code as a parameter", to get executed in a while loop.

Comment: You can pass variable and also functions to functions if that's what you mean?

Comment: So, for example in c#, you can have functions, like the `update()` function in the Unity game engine, where you can define the function as normal if you derive from its class, and the code that you put in that function will be executed every frame. I wanted to do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to have a main `update()` function that calls other `update_x()` functions. By the comments I gather you want to do some sort of game.

You should create a game class first, that contains the update method and instances all other things in the game:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Player()
        self.scenary = Scenary()

    def update(self):
        self.player.update()
        self.scenary.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    game = Game()

    while True:
        game.update()
```

This is assuming those other classes have their own update functions, which would look something like this:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def update(self):
        self.update_movement()
        self.update_collission()
        self.update_status()
```

That way, you can just code in each respective class and everything is going to keep updated each frame by the update functions.

Answer (score 0):

My way of updating different classes that worked for me was to get a list of all classes, and loop through them using a for loop, like so;

```
while True:
  for c in classes:
    try:
      c.Update()
    except:
      pass
```